# Text align always right side of image and with same margin-left

Tags: html, css

I have an image and some text right next to it. When the text is too long, then all the text moves under the image. How to get the text to always align right next to the right of the image always regardless how long the text is. And the text to always be neatly margined line after line (= not that the last lines moves under the image. Is that possible to achieve?

Attached Fiddle...[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/f1xLk74L/7/)

Here my code:

```
 <div class="car">
      <div class="image">
          <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=CAR" />
      </div>
      <div class="makeAndModel">
            <div class="brand">
                Mercedes
            </div>          
            <div class="model">
                W126000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.car {
    display:block;
}

.car .image {    
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.car .image img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

.car .makeAndModel {
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.brand {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
}

.model {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#5A5A5A;
    font-style:normal;
    display:block;
}
```

[image: Desired output]

Comment: sorry, set .model div to specific width with overflow: hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `white-space:no-wrap;` in class .car

```
.car {
    display:block;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f1xLk74L/8/)

**UPDATE**

According to your image, set width of your div which is covered both image and text.

**UPDATE - 1**

I think i got a solution for you,

Here is my [**JSFIDDLE-UPDATE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jj2tqmwm/)

you have to use  `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this style:

```
.car {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

You can also remove `display: block;` from the `car` class, because `div`s default to that style.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d0jd3p0f/)

Comment: sorry, maybe i didnt explain clearly. I put up a picture with my desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Using table-cells you can divide the container into columns like so:

```
.car {
    display:table;
}

.car .image {    
    margin:0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.car .image img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}

.car .makeAndModel {
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.brand {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
}

.model {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#5A5A5A;
    font-style:normal;
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1mb2Lvc4/1/

Comment: Hi, that solution comes close, but is it responsive too? WHat I noticed is that with your solution, the image gets pushed down to the center of all text to the right. Can the image also stay in same position when more text is added? I put up a picture with better explanation.

Comment: You can apply `vertical-align: top` on the `.car .image` selector and `.car .makeAndModel`.

Answer (score 0):

There is only onething that we can do is jus use "..." after the particular length

```
.model{width: 420px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;}
```

No other things can be done